# Calculate the Maclaurin series, using binomial series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image: picture]

Calculate the Maclaurin series for the following function

This is a note from my teacher through email

"Question 5a (this question) is now a bonus question, since it requires
binomial series that we haven't gone over yet.  You are welcome to try
it, but it isn't required."

So what is binomial series and how does that relate to this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: The series expansion can be written using the [*Binomial Series*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: @Amzoti I get that, but I am trying to figure out how that applies to this. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the series representation at the botton of this [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin+series+sqrt%281%2Bx%29-1) page.

Comment: @Amzoti cool! Thanks a lot! That helps a little!

Comment: You can practice with the example, struggle through it and see if you can derive it. It is not bad. maybe you can review the Binomial and have that ready when your teacher reviews it. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti awesome! I will definitely do that! Thanks!